# How do I connect to a QNAP

Tags: ethernet, router, nas, lan, qnap

**BACKGROUND DETAILS:**

I've inhereted a QNAP TS-459U-RP.

I currently have it connected to my home router via an ethernet/rj45 cable.  My computer is connected to the same router.  How do I access the QNAP from my computer?

If I open nautilus and go to `+ Other Locations`, I now see 2 new options under Networks which only become visible if the QNAP is connected to the router and switched on.  The 2 options which become avaible in + `Other locations` are:

NASC3C6BC(FTP)

NASC3C6BC(SAMBA)

---

**THE MESSAGES:**

When I click on the 2 options within Nautilus, I get the following messages:

For the FTP option I get `Opening "qnap-001.local (ftp) You can stop this operation by clicking cancel."`

Nothing happens if I do not click `Cancel`.

For the SAMBA option I get `Unable to access location - Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out`

I then Get an `OK` button.

---

**THE RESET BUTTON:**

I do not know the username and password.  I have checked the manual and it says that I should press the reset button at the back for 3 seconds to reset the admin password and that after 3 seconds it will make a beeping sound.  When I press the reset button at the back for 3 seconds or longer, it makes no beeping sound.

Comment: what have you done after you pressed the reset button for a few seconds?

Comment: Voting to reopen because if you're familiar with a QNAP it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @jsotola after that I tried using the default admin password and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the QNAP using its web GUI. There are lots of manuals, tutorials, etc. at https://qnap.com. Default username is admin, possibly with password admin.

To find its IP address you can either use the QNAP Finder tool (Windows, downloadable from QNAP's website), or look at whatever issues DHCP addresses on your network.

Comment: This answers the question.  Thanks.